# Self Registration -Creating community user is giving User.profileid not writeable

Tags: community, self-registration

. The class is global without sharing . Not able to figure  out what the issue is any help is appreciated

Comment: `without sharing` does not automatically solve all permissions problems - see all answers in the referenced Q&A, they have good suggestions

Comment: this is my class

Comment: Are you using custom self-registration logic?